# How do you sync iPhone 5 with macbook to import iMovies?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, data-synchronization, imovie

I tried to contact Apple for support since I just bought iMovie for my iPhone 5.  They just shut me down, no response.  I figure it was because my macbook is an older model and out of warranty.  I can get my movie clips to show up in iMovie on my macbook.  How do I get the new movies I made on my iPhone into my macbook for editing and filing?

Answer (score 1):

iMovie for Mac and iMovie for iPhone are unfortunately two separate and incompatible tools. You simply won't be able to transfer the iMovie projects to iMovie on Mac.